# How Calculate the first 6 iterations when $x_{0}=0$ of $x_{n+1}=e^(-x_{n})$?

Tags: matlab

How Calculate the first 6 iterations when

```
$x_{0}=0$ of $x_{n+1}=e^(-x_{n})$?
```

My problem is that you make a table with these iterations, I am new to Matlab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the straightforward solution would be a simple `for` loop:

```
x= zeros(1, 6);
for n = 2:6
    x(n) = exp(-x(n - 1));
end
```

Note that indices in MATLAB arrays start from 1, not 0.

Comment: but x_{0} is initial iterate

Comment: @DanielagarciaGarcia So what is the problem? This code gives x(1)=0, x(2)=1, x(3)=e, etc... isn't that what you want?